# ¿Cómo comparar índices de un array?

Tags: javascript, array

¿Cómo podría realizar un `if/else` si dos arrays dentro de un objeto tienen el mismo índice?

```
var Parejas =  {
    hombres: ["Juan","Luis"],
    mujeres: ["Sabrina","Daniela"]
};
```

Así para saber que si los índices de los arrays son iguales, sabría en el contexto de este ejemplo, quién es pareja de quién.

O sea, las parejas se formarían de:

`Hombres[0]` y `mujeres[0]`, y así sucesivamente. O sea, que *Juan* sería pareja de *Sabrina* y **NO** de *Daniela*

Comment: ¿Podrías argumentar mejor tu pregunta? No se entiende mucho lo que intentas preguntar.

Comment: a que te refieren si tienen el mismo indice?

Comment: Me refiero a que array1[0] == array2[0] Mismo índice(indice 0)

Comment: Creo que seria bueno que adjuntaras un ejemplo de lo que quieres hacer en el cuerpo de la pregunta, porque se entiende que quieres armar las parejas, pero no se entiende cual es la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Si tu propósito final es crear las parejas correctas guiándote por el objeto que tienes, lo que podrías hacer es recorrer las propiedades del objeto para ir guardándolas en un `Array` en el índice adecuado. El siguiente `snippet` te dará una idea:

```js
var Parejas = {
  hombres: ["Juan", "Luis"],
  mujeres: ["Sabrina", "Daniela"]
};

var p = [];

for (var prop in Parejas) {

  Parejas[prop].forEach(function (n, i) {
    p[i] = p[i] || [];
    p[i].push(n); 
  });

}

console.log(p);
```

De esta manera no importa la cantidad de propiedades que tengas dentro del objeto podrás emparejarlas todas sin tener que conocer exactamente su nombre:

```js
var Parejas = {
  hombres: ["Juan", "Luis"],
  mujeres: ["Sabrina", "Daniela"],
  hijos:   ["Manuel", "Lucía"],
  madres:   ["Julia", "María"],
  padres:   ["Roberto", "José"]
};

var p = [];

for (var prop in Parejas) {

  Parejas[prop].forEach(function (n, i) {
    p[i] = p[i] || [];
    p[i].push(n); 
  });

}

console.log(p);
```

Ahora, si lo que deseas es hacer una función que al enviarle dos valores te diga si dichos valores pertenecen a una pareja, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
var Parejas = {
  hombres: ["Juan", "Luis"],
  mujeres: ["Sabrina", "Daniela"],
  hijos:   ["Manuel", "Lucía"],
  madres:   ["Julia", "María"],
  padres:   ["Roberto", "José"]
};

function sonPareja (p, n1, n2) {

  var i1 = -1;
  var i2 = -1;

  for (var prop in p) {    
    if (i1 < 0) { i1 = p[prop].indexOf(n1); }
    if (i2 < 0) { i2 = p[prop].indexOf(n2); }
  }
  
  return i1 != -1 && i2 != -1 && i1 === i2;

}

console.log("Juan y Julia => ", sonPareja(Parejas, "Juan", "Julia"));
console.log("Roberto y Lucía => ", sonPareja(Parejas, "Roberto", "Lucía"));
console.log("José y Daniela => ", sonPareja(Parejas, "José", "Daniela"));
console.log("Luis y Julia => ", sonPareja(Parejas, "Luis", "Julia"));
```

Comment: me gusto tu respuesta +1

Comment: Gracias @JackNavaRow. Un saludo ;)

Comment: ChiniNet ayudame, que recibe el forEach, aparte del indice

Comment: @EduardoSebastian, el [prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) recibe en el primer argumento el elemento del `Array`, en el segundo el ínidce del elemento y en el tercero el `Array` en sí.

Comment: y como funciona la parte de  p[i] = p[i] || []

Comment: Lo que hace esa expresión es declarar `p[i]`. Si `p[i]` está definida se queda con su mismo valor, en caso contrario se define con un `Array` vacío. Échale un ojo a [este enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR).

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor es que los emparejes desde que guardes el array.

```js
var parejas = [];

function crear(hombre, mujer) {
  parejas.push({hombre:hombre,mujer:mujer});
}

crear("Juan", "Sabrina");
crear("Luis", "Daniela");

for(var i in parejas) {      
    console.info(parejas[i].hombre + " es pareja de " + parejas[i].mujer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Muy sencillo, los arreglos tienen un método que se llama `indexOf()` el cual te regresa precisamente el índice del arreglo en base al valor o el contenido dentro de este. Te pongo un ejemplo de cómo funciona.

```js
var Parejas =  {
    hombres: ["Juan","Luis"],
    mujeres: ["Sabrina","Daniela"]
};

if (Parejas.hombres.indexOf("Juan") === Parejas.mujeres.indexOf("Sabrina")){
    console.log("Pareja correcta");
    console.log("Índice de Juan: ",Parejas.hombres.indexOf("Juan"))
    console.log("Índice de Sabrina: ",Parejas.mujeres.indexOf("Sabrina"))
}


console.log("Pareja incorrecta");
console.log("Índice de Juan: ",Parejas.hombres.indexOf("Juan"))
console.log("Índice de Daniela: ",Parejas.mujeres.indexOf("Daniela"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es lo que quieres

```js
var Parejas =  {
    hombres: ["Juan","Luis"  ,"Chispas"],
    mujeres: ["Sabrina","Daniela"]
};
var Parejas2 =  {
    hombres: [],
    mujeres: ["Soledad"]
};
emparejar(Parejas);
emparejar(Parejas2);
function emparejar(Parejas){
 var longitud = (Parejas.hombres.length >Parejas.mujeres.length) ? Parejas.hombres.length : Parejas.mujeres.length;
  lasParejas = [];
  for(let i = 0 ; i < longitud; i++){
  let hombre = (typeof(Parejas.hombres[i]) == 'undefined') ? 'se quedo sin hombre' : Parejas.hombres[i]  ;
   let mujeres = (typeof(Parejas.mujeres[i]) == 'undefined') ? 'se quedo sin Mujer' :Parejas.mujeres[i]  ;
   lasParejas.push(hombre . mujeres);
  console.log(hombre , mujeres);
  }
  return lasParejas;
 }
```

Comment: el truco de la longitud es buscar el que tenga mas elementos para recorrerlos

Comment: cual linea en particular @EduardoSebastian